# JS halts Sinatra redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby, http, web, sinatra

I'm writing a blog app in Sinatra. Now I have two pages:

1. **'/'** for listing all my posts
2. **'/write'** for writing a new post

I have an input 'textarea' and a submit button on **'/write'**.

After writing a post and clicking the submit button, I use code below to redirect to the page '/':

```
post '/write' do
    # some codes for storing the new post
    redirect '/', 303
end
```

Here's my problem:

On **'/write'**, if I write some normal texts in the 'textarea' and submit them, everything works fine;

But if I write any javascript in the 'textarea' and submit it, Chrome/Safari do not redirect to the page **'/'** but leave me a blank 'about:blank' page.

I used Chrome developer tool to track the network requests and found no request happened. But if I use Firefox to visit my app, everything works fine. And firebug shows 2 requests happend: POST(303) on **'/write'** and GET(200) on **'/'**.

So I don't know if there is anything wrong with my app or, there are some anti-XSS strategies of Webkit that stopped browsers from loading my **'/'** page? (This page should display my newly submitted post, which is some JS codes. I believe these JS codes cause my 'about:blank' problem).

I appreciate if you can give me any hint and sorry for my poor English.